# Property about the alternating Pascal triangle

Tags: summation, induction, binomial-coefficients

I'm working in a project about sequences and found a problem trying to proof the following equality for any $k$:

*Let $0 \leq m \leq k$*
$$\sum_{i = m}^{k} (-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+1}{i}\binom{i}{m} = (-1)^{k+m}\binom{k+1}{m}$$

I tried with induction, but I'm not able to continue after some point:

*Base case: $k=0$ ($m$ must be $0$)*
$$\sum_{i=0}^{0}(-1)^{i+0}\binom{1}{i}\binom{i}{0} = 1 = (-1)^{0 + 0}\binom{1}{0}$$

*Induction step: supose $\sum_{i = m}^{k} (-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+1}{i}\binom{i}{m} = (-1)^{k+m}\binom{k+1}{m}$*

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{i=m}^{k+1}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+2}{i}\binom{i}{m} &= (-1)^{k+1+m}\binom{k+2}{k+1}\binom{k+1}{m} + \sum_{i=m}^{k}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+2}{i}\binom{i}{m}\\[10pt]
&= -(k+2)\sum_{i=m}^{k}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+1}{i}\binom{i}{m} + \sum_{i=m}^{k}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{k+2}{i}\binom{i}{m}\\[10pt]
& = \sum_{i=m}^{k}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{i}{m}\left(\binom{k+2}{i} - (k+2)\binom{k+1}{i}\right)\\[10pt]
&= \sum_{i=m}^{k}(-1)^{i+m}\binom{i}{m}\binom{k+2}{i}(i-k-1)
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Fun alternate proof: expand $(1-(1-x))^{k+1}$

Comment: To get the induction to work, I’d try to break up $k+2 \choose i$ into ${k+1 \choose i}+{k+1 \choose i-1}$.

Comment: Also, you should just have the sum go to $k+1$ and have it equal 0.

Answer (score 1):

In trying to prove

$$\sum_{q=m}^k (-1)^q {k+1\choose q} {q\choose m}
= (-1)^k {k+1\choose m}$$

we observe that

$${k+1\choose q} {q\choose m}
= \frac{(k+1)!}{(k+1-q)! \times m! \times (q-m)!}
= {k+1\choose m} {k+1-m\choose q-m}$$

and we get for the LHS

$${k+1\choose m} \sum_{q=m}^k (-1)^q {k+1-m\choose q-m}
= {k+1\choose m} \sum_{q=0}^{k-m} (-1)^{q+m} {k+1-m\choose q}
\\ = (-1)^m {k+1\choose m} 
\sum_{q=0}^{k-m} (-1)^q {k+1-m\choose q}
\\ = (-1)^m {k+1\choose m}
((1-1)^{k-m+1}-(-1)^{k+1-m})
= (-1)^k {k+1\choose m}.$$